# What site is best to use for questions about the differences between cleaning products?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I was trying to put oil on my paper shredder for the first time, and I wanted to know how to do it properly.

After going through my shredder's manual, I bought some oil they sell and noticed it had a label stating "contains canola oil." This had me curious, because it also looks like canola oil.

When I googled the difference, I found that *canola* oil is frequently used as a "life hack" in place of *shredder* oil. I wanted to know what the actual difference between the two was. So, I asked on the *[Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site, but they marked [my question off topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/26394/what-is-the-difference-between-canola-oil-and-shredder-oil?noredirect=1#comment38269_26394).

Where can I go to ask technical questions about cleaning products?

Comment: This is why it's [off-topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/26394/what-is-the-difference-between-canola-oil-and-shredder-oil?noredirect=1#comment38269_26394) and [here's a duplicate](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/104994/95727); so that's one [place to ask](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=canola+lubricant).

Answer (score -2):

Home Improvement / DIY Stack Exchange seems to be a good match https://diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Without explaining **why** specific site is fitting, it can fit as a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: No.  Home Improvement is limited to the structure, infrastructure, and certain major appliances that typically convey with the house.  Questions about a shredder wouldn't be on-topic.  The example linked in the question was worded in a general way that let it slip through.